# "To be" or just "be"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, infinitives

Which of these two are more correct?

> 1) When clicking the Edit customer button, I would expect the changes be
>   transferred to the edit view.

or

> 2) When clicking the Edit customer button, I would expect the changes **to** be
>   transferred to the edit view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your choice #2 is correct. The word *expect* must be followed by an infinitive with *to*, so you must say:

> I would expect the changes **to be** transferred...

While the following is ungrammatical:

> *I would expect the changes **be** transferred...

Comment: What if you consider "be" to be the subjunctive form of "to be"? Can't a clause in the subjunctive mood follow the verb "expect"?

Comment: @mac389: that construction would require the complementiser _that_. This might be omitted in casual speech, but for most speakers the subjunctive is incompatible with causal speech.